# Adding web content dynamically with jquery and jstl in a Spring-MVC app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm developing a control panel web app. Now, i have to do an edit user window in order to add or delete roles of the user. I'm thinking in many ways to do it so i would like to ask you how i can afford this in the simpliest way and respecting good practises.

The jsp view has a select with available roles for the user. When you click an option a new div element with a button, rolename and role description has to be displayed. I catch the event with jquery but i have some doubts:

1- How can i pass the username to the jquery function? i'm using jstl but it´s server-side and javascript client-side. Maybe.. i have to do.. /admin/userRoles/john and get the user from the url? Or set a var with jstl? I read about get an attribute model mixing jstl and javascript but it doesn't seem a good practise...

2- Continuing with the jstl and javascript... When i click a select option to select a new role i  need to create a new div with the role info (role name, role description,...) and a button to delete the div. I have a jquery function which captures this event and disable the option of the select. How can i manage to refer the div to the role in order to enable the option if the delete button is selected?
Maybe i have to set the div id with the rolename?

4- The div has a button with a text (delete) but i need to translate it depending on the language. How can i get the translation?

thank you (i will check the most useful answer and vote up the others)

Answer (score 0):

> How can i pass the username to the jquery function?

Just reference nomrally using EL

```
<script>
var yourJsVar = "${yourUsernameVar}";
<script>
```

2,3,4 don't fully understand the question.

You can map spring forms to pojo's easily. Or alternatively submit and return data using Ajax and json, which is also made easy by spring-mvc and jackson. The choice of how you do this CRUD is up to you.

Comment: if i include in the requestMapping method which handles the request of the form: model.addAttribute("user", recordUser); can i get the username from jquery with "${user.username}"?

Comment: i updated the questions. I hope you understand now. Thank you for the reply

Comment: @mannuk "${user.username}" yes, and you can use it anywhere, html element data attributes, a jstl for loop, or within javascript as I  have shown

Comment: also, spring provides lots of internationalization features for multple languages : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource

Comment: if i try: var user = "${user.username}" from my script i can't get the username. it is necessary to declare this var with jstl before?

Comment: nope, just make sure user is added to model, and it has correct getUsername() getter defined, and is not null

Comment: The method includes the user into the model:    model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUser(username)); i can get the username with c:out in the jsp but when i try in the script: var a = "${user.username}" prints the explicit string

Comment: the javascript snippet must be within a jsp, not a sperate js file. You can create var with jstl, but you don;t need to.

Comment: Do you mind to write a full example of what are you explaining?

Comment: its in the answer, its straightforward. Are you using a separate js file, don't.

Comment: It works, now i had a separate js file. For the username it is ok. But if i need a list of elements dynamically is it better to get the list with json? because in this way you can only set the vars at the first moment in the head but it is not possible for example in an event function to do... "${user.username}" or "${user.roles}" to get the list.

Comment: it is possible, read up on jstl and look on this site for examples.